# Spring @Async with Future

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, future

I am new to java.util.concurrent.Future and have some questions. If I call a service using Future how do I know what element was used to call the service?

Here is an example:

1. For each id I am using java.util.concurrent.Future to call a service to fill some extra data.

   ```
   Collection< Future< ObjectX>> future = new ArrayList< Future< ObjectX>>();
   ```

   #### Edit###

   ```
    List< ObjectY> serviceResult= new ArrayList< ObjectY>();

   for (ObjectX obj: ids) 
    {  
      future.add(getAsyncInfo(obj);
    }

   //Because I have a lot of ids i need to call the service @async
   @Async
   public  Future< ObjectY> getAsyncInfo(ObjectX obj){

   return new AsyncResult<ObjectY>(callService(obj));
       ...
    }
   ```

Get the response

```
for (Future<ObjectY> futureResult : future) 
    {               
        serviceResult.add(futureResult.get());
    }
```

In this stage I have a List of results, and I don´t know what result belongs to what id

```
     ids.get(0).setResult(serviceResult.get(0))????
     ids.get(0).setResult(serviceResult.get(1))????
     ids.get(0).setResult(serviceResult.get(2))????
     ...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
class MyResult extends AsyncResult<Object> {
    Object id;
    public MyResult(Object id, Object res) {
        super(res);
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Object getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

@Async
public MyResult getAsyncInfo(Object id) {
    Object res = callService(id);
    return new MyResult(id, res);
}
```

Now you know both result and id. Id and result may be of any type

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can do here.

1. Have your `Collection` of `Future`'s be a `Map` instead (`Map<MyKey, Future<ObjectX>>`)  The key of the `Map` should be some means you can use to map back to your initial `ObjectX`.
2. Have your service return some info on its return value to assist in determining the id.

For 1, I was thinking something like this:

```
//to kick off the tasks
Map<ObjectX, Future<ObjectY>> futures = new HashMap<ObjectX, Future<ObjectY>>();
for (ObjectX id: ids) 
{  
    futures.put(id, getAsyncInfo(id));
}

//...some time later...

//to fetch the results
for(Map.Entry<ObjectX, Future<ObjectY>> entry : futures.entrySet())
{
    final ObjectX id = entry.getKey();
    final Future<ObjectY> future = entry.getValue();
    final ObjectY objY = future.get();
    id.setResult(objY);
}
```

Comment: I´m sorry the result returns a different type of object

Comment: Were 1 or 2 helpful in answering your question? The last paragraph was just a comment on something I observed (which has since been removed due to it no longer being applicable since the question edit).